# If the same shared library is loaded by different applications and from different directories, is it shared in memory?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have been told that in general, Linux will avoid loading multiple copies of the same shared library. My question really is about how robust this mechanism is. If multiple copies of the same library exist in multiple places on your system, will they be shared in memory? Is this any different if you dlopen()'d the library (vs. just linking against it).

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic libraries are loaded (either by the dynamic loader [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) or by [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), which is often using code from `ld.so`) using several calls to the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) syscall.

Generally, the read-only data -and the code- are `MAP_SHARED`. So the RAM (and the memory mapping enforced by the MMU and the kernel) is shared between all the processes.

Of course, what really matters is the [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) which is `mmap`-ed (or `execve`-ed). So two file copies of the same shared library won't be shared. (better use symlinks).

You can understand the memory map of process 1234 by reading sequentially `/proc/1234/maps`. For example, try `cat /proc/$$/maps` in a terminal. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details about `/proc/` pseudo-file system. Try also `lsof`

Answer (score 1):

If the library exists as multiple files on disk, it is **not** shared, as the system has no sensible way of determining that they're actually the same.